# Using $.each() to get data attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

When I used `$('#1').data('title')` to extract the attribute `data-title`, it works.

**Problem:** When I try to extract all the `data-title` attributes from the elements that are the children of div `#collection` using `$.each()`, I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Object 0 has no method 'data'`. What should be the proper way to do this?

**JS Code**

```
$.each( $('#collection').children(), function(index, child) {
    $('#result').append( child.data('title') );
});
```

​

**jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/J5Fjf/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work.

```
$('#result2').html( $('#collection #1').data('title') );

$.each( $('#collection').children(), function() {
    $('#result').append( $(this).data('title') );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#collection').children().each( function(index, child) {
    $('#result').append( $(child).data('title') );
});
```

The second argument in each() would be the native DOM element, while the first argument is the index of the loop. When iterating a jQuery set of elements, you can also use each as a chained function, and `this` would also referrence the element inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

First argument if [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) is `index`, use second.

```
$.each( $('#collection').children(), function(index, child) {
    $('#result').append( $(child).data('title') );
});
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that, I now get the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'data' ` http://jsfiddle.net/J5Fjf/2/

Comment: You need jQuery object to call data on it but you have DOM object, convert it to jQuery object to call data, check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$.each( $('#collection').children(), function(index, child) {
  $('#result').append( child.data('title') );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to catch the index of the divs inside `#collection` and instead of `$.each` you can use `.each` to iterate through:

```
$('#collection div').each(function(i) {
    $('#result ul').append('<li>' + $('#a'+parseFloat(i+1)).data('title')+'</li>');
});
```

chekout the fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/J5Fjf/4/**